# Marten Not Storing Entity

Tags: c#, marten

I'm working with Marten as my data layer and it's been great so far, but I've run into an issue that just doesn't make sense. I have a simple method that saves a transaction (a purchase) then updates a listing, adding the ID of the transaction to a collection. My problem is, it appears that Marten is not storing my updated listing, although it is storing the transaction.

When I look in the database, the TransactionIds property is null, but if I step through the code, everything seems to execute correctly. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
public async Task CreateListingTransactionAsync(ListingTransaction transaction)
    {
        if (transaction == null)
            throw new ValidationException("Transaction is required to create a transaction");

        bool isNew = transaction.Id == Guid.Empty;

        await _listingTransactionValidator.ValidateAndThrowAsync(transaction);

        using (var session = _store.LightweightSession())
        {
            session.Store(transaction);

            if (isNew)
            {
                var listing = await session.LoadAsync<Listing>(transaction.ListingId);

                if (listing == null)
                    throw new EntityNotFoundException($"Listing with Id: {transaction.ListingId} not found");

                if (listing.TransactionIds == null)
                    listing.TransactionIds = new List<Guid>();

                listing.TransactionIds.Add(transaction.Id);

                session.Store(listing);
            }

            await session.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be a problem with the serialization of `TransactionIds` collection.

If that's not the case then here are some random things to try (and try to understand why it worked later):

- Try `session.Update(listing);` instead of `session.Store(listing);`.
- Try different type of document session. http://jasperfx.github.io/marten/documentation/troubleshoot/